# Interesting XHTML/JSTL validation issue

Tags: validation, jsp, emacs, xhtml, logic

I'm using Emacs' `nxhtml-mode` and `mumamo` (multi-major-mode) to validate (and use auto-completion etc.) in real-time on an XHTML page containing some JSTL code.

It's working and I really like what I'm seeing.

I encountered something that I find interesting: I may be misunderstanding what's going on here so I'll try to describe the best I can what is going on and so you can correct me.

Basically I've got the following in the middle of an XHTML that otherwise does fully validate:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <c:forEach var="checkbox" items="${checkboxes}" varStatus="rowCounter">
      <c:if test="${rowCounter.count % 4 == 0}">
        </tr><tr>
      </c:if>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
        ${checkbox.text}
      </td>
    </c:forEach>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now the above does *not* validate using nxhtml.  My Emacs tells me, in realtime:

```
-----... Hg:2588 [(nXhtml/jsp-nxhtml Invalid)]------
```

Because *"Required child element is missing"* for the first closing *tr* tag.  Now it's interesting because I think that the counter starts at one (or can be made to start at one) and hence it's impossible for the validator to "understand" that this first *tr* tag shall never be empty.

I may have got this example wrong, but the idea stays: you can have cases where you know that it's going to be correct but where the validator cannot tell (as far as I can think).

But now what happens if I change:

```
</tr><tr>
```

to:

```
<td></td></tr><tr>
```

Well... Now Emacs thinks everything is fine.

Yet it is not, because if you have a multiple of four entries, then the last line is going to be an empty *<tr></tr>* tag.

I'm interested in knowing two things:

1. how should I fix this particular example? (probably that by inverting the *if* I can make it work, haven't tried yet)
2. can you always fix all such cases that may popup?

I think it's not related to Java: it's related to mixing XHTML and Java/PHP/whatever...  Unless the validator is able to understand what a program does (and we know it's impossible), there are tricky issues like this that are going to pop up no!?

Obviously I do not want to give up the great benefits that realtime validate and contextual auto-completion bring here...

**EDIT** the problem is actually worse than I thought.  You can of course have a .jsp that is well-formed XHTML but which produce an output which is **not** well-formed.  I think there's no way to prevent this in real-time.  However something could maybe be done when the *.jsp* is compiled?  Like giving an error if it notices that the XHTML it produces is not well-formed?